# When should be process context switching faster over thread's one?

Tags: linux

Is there a case where process context switching is faster than thread's one?
In all cases thread switching seems faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got the answer of this question. (From teacher)
Process Switching can be Faster than Thread Switching in 1 case
When there are 2 Processes:
The thread switching between two threads of two different processes is slower than Process switching between two processes

Comment: In this case it's a process context switch anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Process context switching is more time consuming because virtual memory space is completely changed.
I'm not an expert, but I think the context switch of a thread will be always faster than context switch of a process. Perhaps you could have a small (very small) latency if the memory you'll use in the thread about-to-be context switched is not allocated/mmaped yet. However this latency is not in the context switch itself, but while thread is running. I don't really know, only a test can effectively prove it.

Comment: There was a question in my exam to tell atleast one case where Process switching can be faster.. I cant seem to think of such case..